# icon not set as executable icon

Tags: codeblocks, appicon

In my wxSmith project I've changed the resource.rc file and addedd the reference to the icon I want to use:

'''myIcon ICON "images/icon64.ico"'''

The code compile and link correctly and the icon is added in to the .exe target (I can see it by browsing icons in the .exe file), but it is not showed for the executable (ie. Windows File Explorer shows the standard CB icon).

Do I miss something?

Comment: if I leave in the resource file only the reference to my icon, then from file explorer I can see there is effectively only my icon in the executable file but file explorer is still showing the default CB icon. I don't get it.

Comment: well, searching the web I've found a couple of posts reporting that only after a computer restart Windows will show the new icon...